# How to underline text only on 2 line hyperlink with indent

Tags: html, css

I am creating a sidebar menu that has several links, many of them that need to span 2 lines based on the title length and the width requirement of the panel.  The design includes a ">>" as a text bullet so the 2nd line is indented.  I need to make the hyperlink underline on hover, but only the text portion, not the >> or the spaces on the 2nd line.  I've tried dozens of solutions I've found online and this is the closest I've gotten:

http://jsfiddle.net/FbDGL/

Here's the HTML:

```
<font face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color="#00457C" style="font-size: 11pt"><b>
<a href="neuropsychological-assessment.htm">
<font color="#00457C">Neuropsychological Assessment</font></a></b><br>
</font>
<font color="#00457C" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" size="2">
» <a href="adhd.htm">Attention Deficit Hyperactivity<br>
<span class="space">&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>Disorder</a><br>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
a:link {text-decoration: none;
color:#00457C;
}
a:visited {text-decoration: none;
color:#00457C;
}
a:hover {text-decoration: underline}
a:hover .space {text-decoration: none}
a:active {text-decoration: none}
```

It works in IE but does not work in Chrome, Firefox or Safari.  The spaces on the 2nd line are still showing the underline on hover in those browsers.  Can anyone provide me with code that will work in all browsers to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you need to manually add the line breaks or would setting the width of the container be an option?  You really shouldn't use `&nbsp;` for alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the line breaks to be manually added, you can set a hanging indent.  That will not be underlined with the link.

Change your html as follows:

```
<font face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color="#00457C" style="font-size: 11pt"><b>
        <a href="neuropsychological-assessment.htm">
        <font color="#00457C">Neuropsychological Assessment</font></a></b><br>
        </font>
    <div class='div_for_length'>
        <font color="#00457C" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" size="2">
            <div class='link'>»
            <a href="adhd.htm">Attention Deficit Hyperactivity Disorder</a></div>
            </div>
```

And in your CSS rules add these:

```
.div_for_length {
    width: 250px; /* or whatever your needs are */
}

.link {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

As a side note, if you're using CSS, you should avoid `<font>` tags.  These should be expressed in CSS rules.

Comment: This works exactly as I needed it to in all browsers!  I'd vote it up but I'm too new and don't have enough "reputation points".  THANKS!!!

Comment: Glad to help.  If you can't upvote the answer, you should still be able to accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of a list with custom `list-style-image` instead. In the sample bellow I made a image of `»` and base64 encoded it. [Live Deom](http://jsfiddle.net/4Xd2u/)

HTML

```
<div class="some-class">Neuropsychological Assessment</div>

<ul>
    <li><a href="adhd.htm">Attention Deficit Hyperactivity Disorder</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.some-class{
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode";
    color:#00457C;
}
a:link,a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#00457C;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none
}
ul {
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode";
    width:200px;
    list-style-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAYAAADED76LAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH3QwVADcb2iGGJQAAABl0RVh0Q29tbWVudABDcmVhdGVkIHdpdGggR0lNUFeBDhcAAABQSURBVBjTfc8xEkBADAXQt6yCc7mdI2holcYV7Lk0O+zsIFXeT5EEJgRP1XZiQfywHjuO3NcGLWak2k0OArpi7e2IAVsejC+WsBZH1f5/8wJm7g+T7rifRwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg%3D%3D);
}
```

EDIT: You can for sure just set an image as `list-style-image`

Answer (score 0):

use `:before` to make a custom bullet and if you give the link a `width` then the text will automatically go to the next line. http://jsfiddle.net/FbDGL/3/

HTML:

```
<font face="Lucida Sans Unicode" color="#00457C" style="font-size: 11pt"><b>
        <a href="neuropsychological-assessment.htm">
        <font color="#00457C">Neuropsychological Assessment</font></a></b><br>
        </font>
        <font color="#00457C" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" size="2">
         <a href="adhd.htm" class="arrows">Attention Deficit Hyperactivity Disorder</a><br>
```

CSS

```
a:link {text-decoration: none;
    color:#00457C;
    }
a:visited {text-decoration: none;
    color:#00457C;
    }
a:hover {text-decoration: underline}
a:hover .space {text-decoration: none}
a:active {text-decoration: none}

a.arrows:before{
    content: "»";
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
a.arrows{
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

And please dont use this:

```
<font color="#00457C" face="Lucida Sans Unicode" size="2">
» <a href="adhd.htm">Attention Deficit Hyperactivity<br>
<span class="space">&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>Disorder</a><br>
```

it's really sloppy. Keep all the styling in the CSS

`<a href="adhd.htm">Attention Deficit Hyperactivity Disorder</a>`

Comment: This works beautifully in Chrome, but the arrows don't show at all in IE and in Firefox & Safari the arrows are underlining on hover with a space between them and the link text.  Thoughts?