# CSS Text indenting with custom bullet image

Tags: html, css

I know there is a way to keep indent for second line of text in list items. I'm trying to apply the similar effect for a text paragraph with custom list image.

HTML

```
<p>
    <a class="bullet">
        Lorem ipsum dolorsit & consectetur adipisicing
    </a>
</p>
```

CSS

```
.bullet:before {
    background-image:url("../bullet-image.png");
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-position: 10px 5px;
    content:"";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714019/how-to-underline-text-only-on-2-line-hyperlink-with-indent/20714182#20714182

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dyF42/6/)**
CSS :

```
.bullet{
    position:relative;
     padding-left:20px;
    display:block;
}

.bullet:before {
    background-image:url("../bullet-image.png");
    background-position: 10px 5px;
    content:"";
    height:15px;
    width:15px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `indent` with `padding` for your `.bullet` class

```
padding-left: 2em;
text-indent: -2em;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for list-style-position:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/list-style-position

To quote:

> **outside** The value outside causes the list marker to be rendered
> outside the principal block box. Its precise location isn’t defined by
> the CSS2.1 specification. Contemporary browsers seem to render it
> approximately 1.5em to the left of the principal block box in a
> left-to-right environment, or 1.5em to the right of the principal
> block box in a right-to-left environment. Some browsers use padding on
> the list to make room for the marker box, while others use a margin.
>
> **inside** The value inside makes the list marker the first inline box in
> the principal block box. Its exact location is not defined by the
> CSS2.1 specification. Note that when using the value inside should
> text wrap to another line then a situation could occur on short lines
> where the list marker becomes detached from the text (as of course
> would any other inline element).